# Android PixelXorXfermode deprecated

Tags: java, android, android-graphics

I have a old library that used [PixelXorXfermode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PixelXorXfermode.html) class. But it was deprecated in API 17 and removed from API 24.

```
paint.setXfermode(new PixelXorXfermode(-1));
```

I tried to look at its [source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/master/sdk/sources/android-23/android/graphics/PixelXorXfermode.java?autodive=0%2F%2F) and see it call native method.

```
private static native long nativeCreate(int opColor);
```

Is there any alternative for this class? Or is there any way to port it?

Comment: Did you find a work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a good tutorial [here](https://chiuki.github.io/android-shaders-filters/#/14) that explains how to use ColorFilters with lots of examples.  The ["invert" sample](https://chiuki.github.io/android-shaders-filters/#/17) seems accomplish the same thing as PixelXorXfermode.

```
public Bitmap getBitmap(Bitmap original)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(original.getWidth(), 
    original.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(getColorMatrix()));
    canvas.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, paint);

    return bitmap;
}

private ColorMatrix getColorMatrix() {
    return new ColorMatrix(new float[] {
        -1,  0,  0,  0, 255,
        0, -1,  0,  0, 255,
        0,  0, -1,  0, 255,
        0,  0,  0,  1,   0
    });
}
```